# Click and drag not working

Tags: touchpad

So I just updated to Ubuntu 14.10 on my Acer Aspire E5 110, and ever since updating, I have not been able to drag objects onscreen by holding one finger down while dragging the other. The only way I can move windows and whatnot around is by holding one finger down on the track pad and dragging it. Cannot find anything in the settings that would fix this, what can I do to get regular functionality back?
Thanks